# How difficult is production in different fields of contemporary mathematics?

Tags: journals

All of us have heard this before: "publishing a journal paper in area X is more difficult or takes more time than area Y". This is vague, and sometimes people working in area Y may find this kind of comparison offensive, but the question is not a matter of how important, useful, deep, or difficult an area is; rather, it is precisely about the difficulty of the production process. For example, some areas have been studied for a long time, and there is nothing much one could be hopeful to solve in them, or what is left to explore is extremely difficult. My specific question is whether there has been any statistical study for this that compares the rate of production in different fields of contemporary mathematics. I wonder if AMS, MAA, or NSF have done anything in this respect.

Comment: I asked a similar question, recently.

Comment: Wow! This is great! Thank you very much for your prompt response, Mariano!

Comment: Well, I did not get any definitive answers, so ... :)


Comment: @Mariano: could you please give a link to your question, somehow I can't find it. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Hmmm... Why don't you ask AMS, MAA or NSF? And by this, I mean consult their respective websites? I would hope that they would have made available the results of such inquiries. Along slightly different lines, maybe looking at AMS classification on the arxiv would shed some light.

Comment: Or you could try using mathscinet or zentrallblat, if you have access to those. See for instance this question: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/17226/is-discrete-mathematics-mainstream

Comment: Good suggestion, Thierry! I just didn't want to reinvent bicycle, that is why I asked this question in MO!!

Comment: I doubt there is a good answer to this question, if "difficulty of production" means anything deeper than just "rate of publishing".  For example, theoretical computer scientists publish more than mathematicians in some other areas.  Is this because the field is young and it's easier to make important contributions?  Because the field has a culture of hard work?  A culture of lower standards for what is publishable?  Because teaching loads are lower?  Because publishing with students is more common?  Even experts will disagree, and non-experts have little hope of interpreting the statistics.

Comment: Somewhat relevant: Topical Bias in Generalist Mathematics Journals, by Joseph F. Grcar (Notices, Dec 2010).
http://www.ams.org/notices/201011/rtx101101421p.pdf

Comment: As you say (emphasize mine) "sometimes people working in area Y may find this kind of comparison *offensive* " no matter your "but", I think such a discussion might cause problems. (Not that it is not fun or interesting in principle, but this venue seems not made for this.)

Comment: If this is not "subjective and argumentative" I don't know what is. Voting to close.